# Simple matrix calculus but I am struggling to understand

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, calculus, matrix-calculus

Here is my problem: We have $\mathbf{D} \in \Re^{m n}$, $\mathbf{W} \in \Re^{m q}$, and $\mathbf{X} \in \Re^{q n}$. Furthermore, $\mathbf{D} = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{X}$. (NOT an element wise multiplication - a normal matrix-matrix multiply).

I am trying to derive the derivative of $f(\mathbf{D})$, w.r.t $\mathbf{W}$, and the derivative of $f(\mathbf{D})$, w.r.t $\mathbf{X}$.

My class note this is taken from seems to indicate that
$$
\frac{\delta \mathbf{f}}{\delta \mathbf{W}} = \frac{\delta \mathbf{f}}{\delta \mathbf{D}} \mathbf{X}^{T} \text{ and that } \frac{\delta \mathbf{f}}{\delta \mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{W}^{T} \frac{\delta \mathbf{f}}{\delta \mathbf{W}}, 
$$

I understand the chain rule. But I struggle to

1. why tranpose? I struggle to see the transpose, and
2. how come sometimes $\frac{\delta \mathbf{f}}{\delta \mathbf{W}}$ is
   on the left, and sometimes it is on the right. Please try to explain
   as clean and simple as possible. !

Comment: For more explanations and references, please [search this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=matrix+derivative).